# Has SQL changed very much from 2011

Tags: sql

I am considering purchasing a SQL book, [All-in-One For Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470929960), that was written in 2011.

How much has SQL changed since 2011, and are the changes significant enough that it would be pointless to buy this because it is so outdated?

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? (e.g. MySQL, MS-SQL Server, Postgres, etc.)

Comment: Preferably I will be using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table of contents divides *SQL All-in-One For Dummies* into 8 "Books."  As a beginner user of MySQL, you will probably only need to focus on Books 1 through 3, and possibly Book 5.  The good news is that most of the content in these particular Books is material which likely will not have changed much since the book was published in 2011.  So this book should be fine for your particular case.

By the way, you can get the same information for free from the internet.  Here are two great online tutorials for using SQL:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/ - Specific to MySQL
2. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ - General SQL tutorial and reference

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know that you can learn the same things on the internet and I greatly appreciate your suggestions, but I prefer a physically object for basic references. I will use online courses to learn, but for the purpose of my learning style I will be using a book for most of my learning. I was wondering if you recommend any other beginner SQL books? If not that is ok, your answer already greatly helped me. Thank you for your support

Comment: I don't have any books per se, though I can recommend that you read [Tom Jewett's tutorial on database design](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php).  And I can also tell you that basic SQL query syntax doesn't vary that much between flavors, so any highly recommended book on Amazon will probably be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning SQL for querying purposes, here are three things you can look for:

- Avoiding the use of commas in the `from` clause.  You can glance through the book and see if it generally uses the `join` keyword or comma.
- The use of common table table expressions.  These start with `with` at the beginning of the query.
- The use of window/analytic/tanking functions.  These have the `over (partition by . . .)` syntax.  Look in the index to see if `row_number()` is included -- it would be the most common such function.

All three of these have been part of SQL for over a decade, so they *should* be in a book written in 2011.  That is no guarantee that the book was any good then.